# Apex aggregrateresult error

Tags: apex, aggregate, for

Any help why I'm unable to add this?

```
List<AggregateResult> revenue = [select SUM(Daily__c) rev, Client__r.Name from Commissions__c];

Integer totalMonthlyRevenue = 0;
for ( AggregateResult i :revenue ) {
    totalMonthlyRevenue += i.rev;
}
```

Error: Compile Error: Invalid field rev for SObject AggregateResult

Comment: Aggregate return a list so you can use that with .get method in following way. 
 i.get('rev')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't access fields on instances of `AggregateResult` directly. Use the `get` method instead, along with `Integer.valueOf` because the compiler won't like you adding an `Object` to an `Integer`. Give this a shot:

```
totalMonthlyRevenue += Integer.valueOf(i.get('rev'));
```

Comment: Actually, you can cast directly to Decimal instead of using Integer.valueOf, as well. There's a slight performance boost gained by not calling functions.

Comment: I was going off of the type of his `totalMonthlyRevenue` variable. Changing to `(Decimal)i.get('rev');` won't compile, you'd get an illegal assignment from Decimal to Integer. And casting to Integer would throw a runtime conversion error, since that `rev` value will be returned as a Decimal.

But yes, you could cast to Decimal if you changed `totalMonthlyRevenue` to Decimal as well.

Comment: That's true, but I'd recommend changing the variable to decimal, or you'd lose precision. The code could round at the end if they only wanted an integer result.